# Dynamically creating 2 columns on right following each Transposed (row)

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

Looking for VBA solution to produce desired output... Thanks a lot if you have any hints as I am not sure the possible logic/ search keywords to use. And special thanks for those who helped formating my original post.(sorry if I accidentally removed their helpful revisions...). I did struggle to get the table in here. Hope I have improved it (also fixed something).

Below is simplified cleaned "source" data table (otherwise columns might be over 100), the ItemRef starting with Letter are barcodes of Pick, those starting with multiple 0 are barcodes of Drop. They can be duplicate barcode no. This is for one job (RefInt). Prefix1 and Prefix2 are to join Index and ItemRef or Count or Name.

| ItemRef | Count | Prefix1 | Index | Name | CustomData | LegActionType | LegActionNum | LegNum | Legs/0/Title | ExtRef | Prefix2 | LegActionType | Legs/1/Title | Legs/1/LegNum | Legs/1/CustRef | Legs/1/Assets | Title | Ref | RefInt | Expiry Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB3421 | 1 | Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/ | 0 | AB3421 | " " | 16 | 1 | 1 | Pick | null | Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/ | 17 |  | 2 | Dummy | [] | 32/AWS9 | WH1-ST1 | 819 | {moment(new Date()).add(30,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} |
| AB3420 | 1 | Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/ | 1 | AB3420 | " " | 16 | 1 | 1 | Pick | null | Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/ | 17 |  | 2 | Dummy | [] | 32/AWS9 | WH1-ST1 | 819 | {moment(new Date()).add(30,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} |
| 0000458 | 1 | Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/ | 2 | 0000458 | " " | 16 | 1 | 2 |  | null | Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/ | 17 | Drop | 2 | Dummy2 | [] | 32/AWS9 | WH1-ST1 | 819 | {moment(new Date()).add(30,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} |
| 0000458 | 1 | Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/ | 3 | 0000458 | " " | 16 | 1 | 2 |  | null | Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/ | 17 | Drop | 2 | Dummy2 | [] | 32/AWS9 | WH1-ST1 | 819 | {moment(new Date()).add(30,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} |
| 0000458 | 1 | Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/ | 4 | 0000458 | " " | 16 | 1 | 2 |  | null | Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/ | 17 | Drop | 2 | Dummy2 | [] | 32/AWS9 | WH1-ST1 | 819 | {moment(new Date()).add(30,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} |
| 0000458 | 1 | Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/ | 5 | 0000458 | " " | 16 | 1 | 2 |  | null | Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/ | 17 | Drop | 2 | Dummy2 | [] | 32/AWS9 | WH1-ST1 | 819 | {moment(new Date()).add(30,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} |
| 0000458 | 1 | Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/ | 6 | 0000458 | " " | 16 | 1 | 2 |  | null | Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/ | 17 | Drop | 2 | Dummy2 | [] | 32/AWS9 | WH1-ST1 | 819 | {moment(new Date()).add(30,'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')} |

Below is desired output: Note important: I put it in this way, merely because I could not put a very long table into this platform in a readable format after 1 hour...so I transposed the outcome table for viewing purpose only. But the output should not be in this vertical way, but horizontal - as I need create a JSON file from this (csv/excel). And as you can see, each ItemRef has a column of Count and Name created as a group.

| Column Label | Row Label |
| --- | --- |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/0/ItemRef | AB3421 |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/0/Count | 1 |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/0/Name | AB3421 |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/1/ItemRef | AB3420 |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/1/Count | 1 |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/Items/1/Name | AB3420 |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/CustomData |  |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/LegActionType | 16 |
| Legs/0/Actions/0/LegActionNum | 1 |
| Legs/0/LegType | 0 |
| Legs/0/ExtRef |  |
| Legs/0/Title | Pick |
| Legs/0/LegNum | 1 |
| Legs/0/CustRef | Dummy |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/0/ItemRef | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/0/Count | 1 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/0/Name | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/1/ItemRef | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/1/Count | 1 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/1/Name | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/2/ItemRef | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/2/Count | 1 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/2/Name | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/3/ItemRef | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/3/Count | 1 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/3/Name | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/4/ItemRef | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/4/Count | 1 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/Items/4/Name | 0000458 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/CustomData |  |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/LegActionType | 17 |
| Legs/1/Actions/0/LegActionNum | 1 |
| Legs/1/LegType | 0 |
| Legs/1/ExtRef |  |
| Legs/1/Title | Drop |
| Legs/1/LegNum | 2 |
| Legs/1/CustRef | Dummy2 |
| Title | 32/AWS9 |
| Ref | WH1-ST1 |
| RefInt | 819 |
| Expiry Date | 2021-09-25T05:27:30 |

btw: the JSON file looks like this:

```json
   {  
    "Legs": [
          {   "Actions": [
                {    "Items": [
                      {
                         "ItemRef": XXXXXX,
                         "Count": 1,
                         "Name": XXXXXXX
                      },.....
                      ],
                   "CustomData": "",
                   "LegActionType": 16,
                   "LegActionNum": 1,
                }
             ],
             "LegType": 0,
             "ExtRef": "",
             "Title": "Pick",
             "LegNumber": 1,
             "CustRef": "Dummy1"
             },
          { "Actions": [
                {   "Items": [ {
                     "ItemRef": yyyyy,
                     "Count": 1,
                     "Name": yyyyy
                      },
                      .....
                      .....],
    
                "CustomData": "",
                "LegActionType": 17,
                "LegActionNum": 1,
                  }
             ],
             "LegType": 0,
             "ExtRef": "",
             "Title": "Drop",
             "LegNum": "2",
             "CustRef":"Dummy2",
             "Assets": []
          }
       ],
       "Title": "32/AWS9",
       "Ref": "WH1-ST1",
       "RefInt": 819,
       "Expiry Date": "2021-09-25T05:27:30" 
       }
```

Hi,@[peh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%E1%B4%87%CA%9C) , @[Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) , @[braX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422953/brax)
Thank you very much again for your generous help.

Edit: hope this table is better.

Comment: thank u everyone for helping reformat my question. that's very kind of you. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"wrapping up each Transposed row"*? It is very unclear what your goal is. How would that nested JSON file have to look like. Please see [mcve] and provide a full example of input data and desired output data as well as what you have tried to solve your problem (see [ask]).

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ , thanks for your comment,  I tried to improve the format...I added the info about the JSON file in the post. Thank you.

Comment: 2 more questions: 1. do you really need that tranposed table or just the JSON? 2. can you show how the JSON would look like for the data in table 1 instead of that generic JSON with "Dummy" data?

Comment: hi @Peh, thanks. the part i am involved in is basically transform the structure using vba... i was given a JSON template with all dummy data which was said works ok when posted to an api platform..i used that reverse engineered csv (from the json file) thru a web tool to see what the structure it should be (as the original data file is a pipe delimited text file...)...i feel this project seems way beyond vba capability with so many unknown...

Comment: i mean, the JSON file is final aim, i only have the keys as template,  dummy data is said will work but no guarantee will be accepted by the system...(the final goal is to create a job...) sorry for so much ambiguity in this.